# Windows server 2008 R2 - time limit for locked session?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Question on Windows Server - if I remote desktop into a server, and then proceed to the lock the screen (rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation), and close the window...because I wanted to keep a process running on that machine...

Is there a time when that locked session expires or fizzles out and becomes disconnected?

If the session became disconnected, that process I was running earlier may not function.

Or....does it stay good for as long as no one logs into that account again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend if any policy settings that have been set to limit the time.
Both the User & Computer sections of policy offer several kinds of time limits at the following path:
`...\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits`

- End a disconnected session
- Active session limit
- Idle session limit
- When a session limit is reached or connection is broken

More here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272(v=ws.11).aspx